# Can anyone please identify this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, invertebrates

[image: what is this?]

We saw this leech like worm in Kerala, India. Can anyone identify it for us? I saw it today, 10th September. It's about 6 to 7 centimeters long. It was very still, didn't move while we went close and took a picture. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. Most importantly, how big is that? Is it a centimeter? A meter? What time of year did you see it? What time of day?

Comment: It does not look like a leech to me. Looks more like a millipede. Did it have legs?

Comment: None that we could see.